# Docker containers requests return Error: read ECONNRESET

Tags: docker, docker-compose, micronaut

I am using docker-compose to start two containers: one with a micronaut service and one with postgres.

This is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  web:
    image: "time"
    container_name: "time"
    build:
      context: .
      network: bridge
    ports:
      - "8081:8080"
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - "db"
    environment:
      - PGHOST=db
      - PGDATABASE=postgres
      - PGUSER=postgres

  db:
    image: "postgres"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: time
```

But when I try to send a request to one of my endpoints, nothing happens until eventually I get a Error: read ECONNRESET

Of course when I run my app in my PC outside of docker, I can send requests fine. Is there anything wrong with my set up?

This other set up works fine, but I'd like to know how to get the two containers to connect like in my first docker-compose AND being able to access them from my host.

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  web:
    image: "time"
    container_name: "time"
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - PGHOST=db
      - PGDATABASE=postgres
      - PGUSER=postgres
    network_mode: host

  db:
    image: "postgres"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: time
    network_mode: host
```

Comment: Connection between `web` and `db` works?

Comment: @Howaboutnope I'm pretty sure it does because earlier my web wouldn't start because it couldn't connect to db and I managed to fix that.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I finally got it!

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  web:
    image: "time"
    container_name: "time"
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - "db"
    environment:
      - PGHOST=db
      - PGDATABASE=postgres
      - PGUSER=postgres
    network_mode: bridge

  db:
    image: "postgres"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: time
    network_mode: bridge
```

Comment: what exactly was the change for the fix?